# Why am I not getting hits for *Nun ke* in Tekstaro if it's a valid expression?

Tags: technology

A question was asked recently in which the asker attempted to answer his own question and was on the right track to do so, however, he found no hits for *nun ke* in the Tekstaro which suggested to him that this was not a valid expression.

How can we search in Tekstaro to find things like this and answer our own question?

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, you needed to search for the expression with punctuation included:*nun, ke*

The following highlighted parts are search terms I used.

> nun ke

This pulls up a ton of false hits, so I added the sign for word boundries.

> \bnun ke\b

This gives one hit, but it's a false hit. I tried with a real comma.

> \bnun\, ke\b

This shows a number of interesting results.

You can also search commas without a slash. It appears to give the same result.

It also helps to uncheck the box *Atenti usklecon*

Comment: It's also possible to use regular expressions when unsure: `\bnun[^a-zA-Z]+ke\b` (this matches anything that's not letters between the two words). Here it's a bit of overkill but may come in handy in other cases.

Comment: That's great. I'm making a note of that one. In this case, it pulls it up with and without commas.

Comment: Note you could shorten that to `\bnun\W+ke\b`. `\w` means any letter and `\W` matches any non-letter. This has the added advantage that it takes into account the Esperanto letters with hats.